# Leaflet activearea interferes with esri-lealet imagelayer

Tags: raster, leaflet, feature-layer, esri-leaflet, distortion

I am creating a leaflet application that uses various data sources / map layers.  I found a great source for [global ground cover](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1770449f11df418db482a14df4ac26eb) from esri.  It is an imageLayer.  Using an [esri-leaflet imageLayer](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/image-map-layer.html), I am able to add this layer to my map.  My application will likely need to draw data from various raster layers like this one.  I am also able to load an [urban-wildland boundary](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a4985d64969743db8feddf01c96c9435) layer as an [esri-leaflet featureLayer](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/feature-layer.html).

I am also using [leaflet-active-area](https://github.com/Mappy/Leaflet-active-area), which is a plugin that shifts the center and bounds of the map to the `div` of your choosing.  I love this plugin for creating a better UI experience.

The `featureLayer` works just fine in conjunction with the `activeArea`.  However, the `imageLayer` is having problems.  It seems that the `imageLayer` is calculating what section of the layer should be currently in the map based on the original map bounds, but then squishing the image itself into the `activeArea` div.  Check it out:

[image]

### [Working demo of the problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/activearea-vs-esriimagelayer-7xo7o)

I made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/activearea-vs-esriimagelayer-7xo7o) that shows this problem.  There is a 'toggle activearea' button there, so you can see how the `imageLayer` works properly when not using the activearea, but has this issue when using it.

What might be going wrong here?  What is it about an `imageLayer` (or its underlying `L.ImageOverlay`) that it knows to sample the correct bounds from the entire map, but then it squishes it into the activearea, instead of the total area?  I tried using other types of esri layers (L.esri.tiledMapLayer, L.esri.dynamicMapLayer, etc.) but these don't work as they are not the correct functions to recieve and apply this layer source.  I don't want to give up my `activearea`, but I'm going to need to apply and ready from raster layers in my application.   Ideas?

Thanks for reading.

#### Edit: altering codesandbox to use public esri imagemaplayer

I had been using an auth-requires esri imagemaplayer in my initial example, which had my personal `client_id` and `client_secret` exposed.  I changed it to use a public layer for esri so people can still view the problem.  Also,

#### [Here is a codesandbox with the patch / fix js file](https://codesandbox.io/s/activearea-vs-esriimagelayer-patch-g2upg)

But thanks to TomazicM for getting to the crux of the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem stems from the fact that `esri-leaflet` image layer is calling Leaflet map `getBounds()` method, which is modified by `leaflet-active-area` plugin to return only active area bounds instead of map bounds. As a consequence ESRI image layer is rendered inside active area only.

Brute force method to remedy this is to modify `getBounds()` method again and in case of ESRI layer use normal `getBounds()` procedure. To detect that `getBounds()` method is called from `esri-leaflet` plugin, I'm using hacking method of checking call stack for `esri` string. This is dependant on implementation and should be changed accordingly.

So to achieve desired behavior, the following code has to be placed before map definition:

```
L.Map.include({
  getBounds: function() {
    var trace = new Error().stack;
    if (this._viewport && (trace.search(/esri/i) == 0)) {
      return this.getViewportLatLngBounds();
    } else {
      var bounds = this.getPixelBounds(),
      sw = this.unproject(bounds.getBottomLeft()),
      ne = this.unproject(bounds.getTopRight());
      return new L.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes!  This does it.  I knew the answer was related to the way `L.esri.RasterLayer` uses `getBounds`, and the fact that `activeArea` modifies it, but I got lost trying to pinpoint how to separate them out.  The only thing about your answer is that it uses `Error().stack`, which mozilla says its a big no no in production code.  I recycled some of your code and did some `L.esri.RasterLayer.include({ ... })`, making it more production-friendly.  Its a little messy, but it works the same.  [Check it out](https://codesandbox.io/s/activearea-vs-esriimagelayer-tomazicm-extended-answer-nx763)

Comment: I do feel like the way I wrote my `L.esri.RasterLayer.modification` file might not be the most slim it can be.  I end up importing a bunch of things from leaflet and esr-leaflet just to make sure they're in the namespace, even though they're already imported when leaflet and esr-leaflet are imported.  This would enlarge the bundle size.  If you're curious, any ideas how to streamline this, without importing these components again in my modification file?

Comment: I see you went for esri-leaflet plugin modification, which is the right way, I just didn't want to touch it beacuse it's more complex. Since I'm not familiar with Node.js environment, I can't comment on your implementation. As for using `Error().stack` method, I knew it's questionable, it was just quick momentary hack (at my job :-).

Answer (score 0):

I finally got around to making an npm package to fix this issue.  You can check it out here:

## [esri-leaflet-active-area-patch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esri-leaflet-active-area-patch)

Maybe I'll get around to putting in a PR to the esri-leaflet repo one day so that you don't need to use the patch.  Until then, its available for the one in a million chance someone else needs it.